# how to query with ormlite by using ISO8601 date formats in android

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

Hi i want to query for all of the rows/objects in the db table that have have a `timeStamp` in ISO8601, bigger than a date `baseDate`(ISO8601) , Im using the Ormlite as framework,so please suggest a solution that uses Ormlite.

Here is a simple example of my model.

```
@DatabaseTable(name="testTable")
class testTable
{
     @DatabaseField(id = true)
     int id
     @DatabaseField
     String timeStamp
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use :

```
private TimeStampType timeStamp;
```

As the data type and "QueryBuilder" with a where clause.